# Inverse of gmtime_r function

Tags: time, timezone, posix

Is there a predefined inverse of gmtime_r? mktime converts it as if it were local time. Do I need to pick up current time-zone and correct it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `timegm()` function.

In my man page (OS X), it's described in the same paragraph as `mktime`. On Linux, it's listed in the `SEE ALSO` section.

Comment: On the man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timegm.3.html, timegm() is listed as a nonstandard GNU extension which leaves me to wonder about how widely it is supported.  That same man page suggested a portable algorithm that involves setting environment variables.

Comment: True. Although it also says that the definition is available with feature test macros `_BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE`. That probably covers most Unix flavors you're likely to encounter, but maybe not some non-Unix POSIX environments.